# favicon not loading simple implementation

Tags: html, favicon

I have looked over pretty simple implementations of how to implement a favicon.

The following code is on the landing page of my website:

```
<!-- Icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="Pictures/logo.jpg">
```

Strangely the icon is not loading, am I required to load a specific library? I know that the image does not necessarily need to be compressed into a 16x16 image. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure your folder is named `Picture` (with capital `P`)? Are you running on Linux/Unix?

Comment: Did you check the browser's console output to verify if it is at least trying to load an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jpg` files is not recommended for `favicons` (by the way, IE does not support it). It is recommended to use `ico` and `png` formats which are supported by all browsers.

It is also recommended to place the files in the root of your website. Some browsers only support `favicons` in the root.

However, it is very complex to create `favicon` files that will look good in all browser (including smart phones and tablets). Check [this article](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/) for more details, and it contains a very nice generator.

Comment: the only problem I'm now having is with the favicon next to the url, strangely the favicon only loads for the browser tab but not next to the URL

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Chrome does not support `favicon` in the address bar. Check this [Article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) to see how `favicon` is supported in different browsers.